# Wrapping title text in CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am hoping to make the title of blog posts wrap onto a second line as can be seen on blog.buffer.com

I can’t find anything obvious in the code when inspecting the elements on the Buffer blog that would control this and wondered if anybody has achieved this?

Many thanks

Comment: reduce the width of the element that contains the text. The text should wrap automatically if it does not have explicit set rules for not doing so.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

use custom css using class name of the tittle text. Mainly custom css field found in Theme option or you can add custom css plugin available for free.